# Oilaf driver updates?

Tags: drivers, graphics

I've installed Oilaf graphics driver from here:

[Oilaf graphics driver](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers)

But keeps updating the same items in loop, like lib1gl or opengl apis, any idea what I can do to update normally?

Comment: What do you mean by "updating the same items in loop"?

Comment: I meant as the same items listed to update, for example libgl 12.1 and few others, exact same things over and over everytime I turn on my pc

Comment: If you mean you are constantly getting updates from the PPA, that is expected because the PPA is extremely active. I use the Oibaf PPA too.

Comment: I fixed my prob with the command: 'sudo apt-get autoclean' some files were repeated edwinksl